# combining columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have list of columns that I want to combine into a vector.  The column element could be a name or the string "0".  I would like to get a list of the column's elements that have a name into a character vector called `df$keywords`.  I have pasted an example dataframe below. I would like it to become

`df$keywords[1,]` would be an empty vector

`df$keywords[2,]` would be (`ACT Science`, `study skills`, `MCAT`)

Any help would be appreciated

```
    structure(list(V31 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), V32 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "ACT Science", 
    "English", "Microsoft PowerPoint", "physics", "proofreading", 
    "reading", "writing"), class = "factor"), V33 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
    V34 = structure(c(1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("0", 
    "geography", "Italian", "literature", "prealgebra", "SAT reading", 
    "study skills", "trigonometry"), class = "factor"), V35 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
    V36 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("0", 
    "English", "MCAT", "precalculus", "proofreading", "SAT writing", 
    "writing"), class = "factor"), V37 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
    V38 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("0", 
    "English", "GED", "physical science", "reading", "spelling"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V31", "V32", "V33", "V34", 
    "V35", "V36", "V37", "V38"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))
```

Comment: hi, sorry, but this isn't making too much sense.  What you describe as output does not match up with the sample data. Also, do you want to combine them into a `vector` or into a `data.frame`?   Please consider revising your question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data in assigned to `x` then the following achieves what I think you are after:

```
apply(x, 1, function(r) {tmp <- unique(r); tmp[tmp != 0]})
```

`apply` works across each row of your data frame, takes the unique elements in each row and gets rid of `0` entries. The results are a list of vectors of varying lengths with the unique non-zero elements of each row.

Comment: Small typo: `apply(x` should be `apply(tmp` I think?

Comment: the more compact way of writing this would be `apply(df, 1, function(r) unique(r[r != 0]))`

Comment: @SlowLearner no typo!! `x` is the object to `apply` the function over. To be applicable to the OP's data it should be `apply(df...)` but I think sean is giving the general case.

Comment: @SimonO101 Ah, yes, I had actually named my data `tmp` rather than `x` when I looked at it so of course that worked, but I was getting the wrong end of the stick. Apologies for mudding the water and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In first post I did not correctly understand the required output, A *slightly* different approach would be to use the `%in%` operator across rows like this:

```
df$keywords <- apply(df,1, function(x) c( x[! x %in% "0"]))
df$keywords
#                                                                                                            keywords
#1                                                                                                                    
#2                                                    ACT Science, study skills, MCAT, ACT Science, study skills, MCAT
#3      Microsoft PowerPoint, prealgebra, precalculus, reading, Microsoft PowerPoint, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#4                                physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading, physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#5                                    reading, trigonometry, writing, English, reading, trigonometry, writing, English
#6                                                            writing, geography, English, writing, geography, English
#7  proofreading, SAT reading, SAT writing, physical science, proofreading, SAT reading, SAT writing, physical science
#8                                physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading, physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#9                                            English, Italian, proofreading, GED, English, Italian, proofreading, GED
#10                           English, literature, proofreading, spelling, English, literature, proofreading, spelling
```

And if you want the `unique` set of skills per row, just add in the command `unique` like so:

```
df$keywords <- apply(df,1, function(x) c( unique(x[ ! x %in% "0" ] ) ) )
df["keywords"]
#                                                  keywords
#1                                                          
#2                           ACT Science, study skills, MCAT
#3    Microsoft PowerPoint, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#4                 physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#5                   reading, trigonometry, writing, English
#6                               writing, geography, English
#7  proofreading, SAT reading, SAT writing, physical science
#8                 physics, prealgebra, precalculus, reading
#9                       English, Italian, proofreading, GED
#10              English, literature, proofreading, spelling
```